# Database Mail configuration in 2023 onward

Tags: sql-server, smtp

I've been using *Database Mail* successfully for about ten years, but it seems that while mail protocols and security have moved forward, SQL Server *Database Mail* has not.

At a new company, I've spent a full work day already trying various credentials and parameters.  The most recent release I have tested with is SQL Server 2019.

What I believe I need to know is how to configure SQL Server Database Mail to work with one of the following:

1. Office 365 or Exchange SMTP
2. Windows [Server] SMTP relay

In tests with GMAIL/SMTP, AT&T/SMTP and Earthlink/SMTP, all returned errors, and at least some of the error messages are clearly from the destination SMTP service and not the result of firewall or connectivity problems.  For example:

> The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 8 (2023-01-06T11:14:56). Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required - ELNK003_308 - https://postmaster-earthlink.vadesecure.com/outbound_error_codes/#_308).  )

Unfortunately, error 308 is not actually documented within the linked Earthlink page.

Looking into some available posts, I find that *Database Mail* is said to use the *SmtpClient* class, which in turn is pretty much obsolete, with recommendations to use *MailKit*.  That's fine, but SQL Server Database Mail has apparently NOT been updated to use *MailKit*.

Returning to what I think are my choices are from above:

1. If I am to configure SMTP to Office 365 (we already have an account) or Exchange (if we have Exchange also), then what SMTP configuration parameters do I need to use with *Database Mail* and within Office 365?

=OR=

2. If I am to use Windows Server SMTP relay, then how do I configure the SMTP relay's OUTPUT mail to satisfy to the "modern" security requirements of Office 365, GMAIL, Earthlink or AT&T?

   (I've used the Windows Server SMTP relay in years past, but only to offload the messages from SQL Server, not to satisfy security requirements)

Comment: Don't know if intentional, but your "previously" link was to Edit mode (I got out of it).  That includes at least one item (supportedFramework) that I hadn't encountered before.  Bottom line, should all be useful as limited resources on-site.  Thx.   
I'm not sure yet if the company I'm at is using Office 365 directly or still using Exchange, so I left open the possibility of using the Windows Server SMTP relay.

Comment: Regarding comment about "applications", the question I ask is less whether the use case is an "application", and more whether the data / executing code originates in SQL Server.  ###

I don't think my companies' code has ever reached down into SQL Server from c# to send an email, but if a stored procedure has something to say about it's operation, I'm certainly comfortable calling sp_send_dbmail.